# Robotium: HowTo create a test project for an existing project in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, project, robotium

I'm stuck in creating a test project for an existing one.
For Eclipse it was simple, but for IntelliJ(and I'm forced to use it at my workplace) I don't really know how to test the project using Robotium framework.
I would appreciate if anyone can write few clear steps in order to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ, you create modules for this.

```
File -> Add Module -> Create Module from Scratch -> Android -> Test
```

For setting up Robotium in your new test project, open up

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> <your test project> -> Add
```

Then add the Robotium jars with it.