# Robotium: Problems with importing Android Robotium project from Eclipse into IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robotium

I've got project originally written in Eclipse as a separate Robotium project for the application project, that need to be tested. I wanted to import it into IntelliJ IDEA.
The problem with IDEA is connected with visibility of that application project, I guess. 
I've added it as a module dependency, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718920/robotium-howto-create-a-test-project-for-an-existing-project-in-intellij-idea). But it didn't help. 
IDEA still throws compilation errors like:

```
type parameter com.***.MyActivity is not within its bound    
cannot find symbol constructor Solo(android.app.Instrumentation, com.***.MyActivity)
```

Any advice?

Comment: How exactly did you add the dependency? Did you configure the test module to depend on the application module or vice versa? What scope did you use? If there are other libraries in either of the projects, you may need to enable the **Export** option so that they are also available. It would help a lot if you can share a test project to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I think the missing point was to enclose all other libraries and enable the Export option for them. Before I added only application project as dependency module with scope:provided and marked Export option for it, but that was not enough. Now, I have added all libraries from application project to test project, marked them for Export with scope: provided. It seems it's working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the information, I've moved it to the answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when you set dependencies between modules, libraries of the module will not be available for the other module by default, one needs to explicitly enable the **Export** checkbox for the corresponding libraries.